# Spring Cloud Contract Gradle - How to access constants defined in main source set in contract DSL?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

The question is how to access constants defined in `main` source set in contract DSL.

I have a simple class that holds constants - it is part of `main` SourceSet :

```
package io.mkrzywanski.pn.user.app.infra;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class UserServiceConstants {
    public static final String USER_SERVICE = "user-service";

    public static final class Paths {
        public static final String VERSION = "v1";
        public static final String USERS = VERSION + "/users";
    }
}
```

I would like to access constants defined in this class in my contract class :

```
import io.mkrzywanski.pn.user.app.infra.UserServiceConstants
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    request {
        method(GET())
        url("/v1/users/1")
    }
    response {
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        status(404)
        body([
                timestamp: "${nonEmpty()}",
                message  : "User with id ${fromRequest().path(2)} not found",
                status   : 404,
                serviceName: "${UserServiceConstants.USER_SERVICE}",
                path: "${UserServiceConstants.Paths.USERS}"
        ])
    }
}
```

However when `generateContractTests` task is invoked in gradle I receive compilation error:

```
@ line 3, column 1.
   import io.mkrzywanski.pn.user.app.infra.UserServiceConstants.
userDetailsNotFound.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class io.mkrzywanski.pn.user.app.infra.UserServiceConstants
```

I know that it is possible to have a separate jar with classes which could be added to the test scope but I kinda do not understand why the former does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the plugin's classpath is a different classpath then the project classpath. You need to explicitly tell Gradle / Maven that there is additional code that needs to be attached to the classpath when the plugin is being executed.

Comment: You are right. I inspected the source code of gradle and it turns out that this task uses classpath from `contractTestGeneratorRuntimeClasspath` configuration which extends `contractTestRuntimeClasspath` (cannot find where this one is defined). However adding `contractTestGeneratorRuntimeClasspath sourceSets.main.output` to `dependencies` block worked. Still curious why adding a jar with classes to `testImplementation` makes those classes visible to `generateContractsTests` task.

Comment: AFAIR it doesn't - it only gives you code completion.

Comment: When I said that it works I meant that it works with common module like in [`spring-cloud-samples`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/a3721c095ceab5e2e6d72af7b9f70c46db962af3/producer/build.gradle#L44). The common jar is added to `testImplementation` and then I can invoke `ProducerUtils` methods in contract directly.

Comment: With this on the classpath your IDE will help you with code completion. It doesn't mean that the plugin will be able to generate the tests.